# Content is positioned underneath fixed top nav bar

Tags: html, css, position, navbar

I'm creating an Instagram clone with React and am now having trouble setting up my title bar. I set it to `position: fixed;` so that it would sit up top horizontally but now my picture gallery sits directly behind it, overlapped by the title bar. I've tried adding `padding-top` to both the `body` and `.gallery` (separately) but that just moves everything down (still overlapping) by however much I set it. It's also the same with adding `margin-bottom` to the `.space` div. I would like for my picture gallery to sit below my title bar. My `app.js` is plugged into its own `<div>` inside the `<body>` tag by `ReactDOM.render()`. Here is my JSX:

**app.js**

```
 return (
  <main>
    <div className="bar">
      <div>
        <h1 className="title">boy walks dog</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div className="gallery">
      {mappedImageCollection}
    </div>

    <div>
      {overlay}
    </div>
  </main>
 )
```

And here is my CSS:

```
   body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-image: url('../img/pattern7.png');
   } 

   .gallery {
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     justify-content: space-around;
     align-items: center;
     max-width: 80%;
     margin: auto;
    }

   .bar {
     position: fixed;
     background-color: #C26464;
     width: 100%;
     box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give the navbar a bottom margin of how much you want it to be spaced out

or

Try this

add this to your html inbetween the two elements

```
<div class="spacer">
</div>
```

then in your css

```
.spacer{
    display: block;
    height: //how much space you want between the two elements 
    content: '';
}
```

Comment: The spacer div worked but I'm wondering why adding a `bottom-margin` to the `.bar` isn't working?

Comment: No idea what happens when you play around with it in the dev tools?